# Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64

Tags: centos7, php7

I cant install php-bcmath via `yum install php-bcmath` because got this error message

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.netonboard.com
 * epel: mirror.vorboss.net
 * extras: centos.netonboard.com
 * updates: centos.netonboard.com
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.4.16-45.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-45.el7 for package: php-bcmath-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-45.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.2()(64bit) for package: php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip.x86_64 0:0.10.1-8.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php71w-common-7.1.22-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.1
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How to remove completely the `php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64` from my Centos 7? I'm using laravel 5 for my project. Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: I continue from SO...*Please advice. Thank you.* Is irrelevant; same as the fact that you are using Laravel. Anyway did you read the errors and did you tried the suggested steps?

Comment: @Kyslik the suggested steps won't work when explicitly installing incompatible versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `php71w-bcmath` instead of `php-bcmath`. `php-bcmath` belongs to PHP 5 and you seem to be using PHP 7.1.